# Bootstrap 4 Landing page to added right side image cant put to correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Im tried to added bootstrap 4 my sample project to right side background , I have some conflict on this, i tried to put it right side , its not working, anyone know how to do that correctly

Thanks

```js
// Navbar scroll js //

jQuery(function($) {
    "use strict";

        // get the value of the bottom of the #main element by adding the offset of that element plus its height, set it as a variable
        var mainbottom = $('#main').offset().top;

        // on scroll,
        $(window).on('scroll',function(){

        // we round here to reduce a little workload
        stop = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());
        if (stop > mainbottom) {
            $('.navbar').addClass('past-main');
            $('.navbar').addClass('effect-main')
        } else {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('past-main');
       }

      });


  // Collapse navbar on click

   $(document).on('click.nav','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('a') ) {
    $(this).removeClass('in').addClass('collapse');
   }
  });


    /*-----------------------------------
    ----------- Scroll To Top -----------
    ------------------------------------*/

    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
          $('#back-top').fadeIn();
      } else {
          $('#back-top').fadeOut();
      }
    });
    // scroll body to 0px on click
    $('#back-top').on('click', function () {
      $('#back-top').tooltip('hide');
      $('body,html').animate({
          scrollTop: 0
      }, 1500);
      return false;
    });




  /* ------ jQuery for Easing min -- */

    // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
    $('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').on('click', function () {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 54)
          }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
          return false;
        }
      }
    });

    // Closes responsive menu when a scroll trigger link is clicked
    $('.js-scroll-trigger').on('click', function () {
      $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    });

    // Activate scrollspy to add active class to navbar items on scroll
    $('body').scrollspy({
      target: '#mainNav',
      offset: 54
    });










});
```

```css
/*----- Main Classes -----*/

html * {
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}





/* --- Font Styles ---*/

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 16px;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 14px;
}






/*------  Navbar Styling ------*/

.navbar {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease;
    transition: 0.5s all ease;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #563D7C;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler {
    border: none;
}

.navbar span.navbar-toggler-icon::before {
    outline: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.navbar-nav {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: 0.5s all ease;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #563D7C;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    color: #563D7C;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.nav-white .nav-item .nav-link {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav-white .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
    color: #F1F1F1;
}

.nav-white .navbar-brand {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    .navbar {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.99) !important;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .nav-white .navbar-brand {
        color: #4957B8;
    }
    .nav-white .nav-item .nav-link {
        color: #4957B8;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 240px) {

    .navbar.past-main {
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.99) !important;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.3);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.3);
    }

    .navbar.effect-main {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }


    .nav-white.past-main .nav-item .nav-link {
        color: #4957B8;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

    .navbar.past-main .nav-item .nav-link {
        font-weight: 500;
    }

    .nav-white.past-main .navbar-brand {
        color: #4957B8;
    }

    .nav-white.effect-main {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    /*----------------------------------------------------------
    --------------- 3. Hero Home Styling Starts -------------------
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/

    .home-section h4 {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #b2bcc1;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        line-height: 1.2;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .home-section img {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }


    .hero-home h1 {
        font-size: 32px;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        color: #FFF;
        line-height: 1.2;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
    }

    .home-section h1 {
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #364655;
        color: #FFF;
        line-height: 1.2;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
    }

    .hero-home p {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: #EFEFEF;
        color: #FFF;
        line-height: 1.6;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .home-section p {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: #627382;
        color: #FFF;
        line-height: 1.6;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    /*---------- home-section Styling --------------- */
    .home-section {
        padding: 100px 0 50px 0 !important;
        background:#4529f9 ;height: 100vh;
        min-height: 40rem;
        padding-top: 72px;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }

    .home-section .home-content {
        text-align: center;
    }











    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------
    ------------------  Media Queries  -------------------
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    @media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {

        .navbar-nav {
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        .navbar-nav .nav-item {
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-right: 15px;
            font-size: 0.85rem;
            font-weight: 400;
        }


        .home-split .home-left {
            padding: 200px 20px 150px 20px;
        }

        .home-section {
            padding: 150px 0 150px 0 !important;
        }

        .home-section.col-sm-5 {
            -webkit-box-flex: 0;
            -webkit-flex: 0 0 50%;
            -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
            flex: 0 0 50%;
            max-width: 50%;
        }
    }
}


.banner-one {



    width: 100%;

    background-image: url(http://brotherslab.thesoftking.com/html/lotten/demo/assets/images/shape/banner-one.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 880px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;


    background-size: 68%;
    background-position: top right;



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap , Main CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
   

    <!-- fontawesome kit -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04ca3524f6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!---Nav bar section--->

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md nav-white navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Label</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto navbar-right">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#main">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Features</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Buy Now</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

</div>

<!---End of Nav bar section--->


<!---Home section--->
<div id="main" class="main">
    <div class="home-land home-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-center">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="home-content">
                        <h4>Label for your big data needs</h4>
                        <h1>Manage all your data at just one place</h1>
                        <p>Best in class big data software and analytics services will render your chunks into meaningful data.</p>
                        <div class="subform subform-alt wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                            <form id="signup" class="formee formee-alt" action="assets/php/subscribe.php" method="post">
                                <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><input class="right inputnew" type="submit" title="Send" value="Get Access" />
                            </form>
                            <div id="response"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-note">
                            <p>14-day free trial and no credit card required.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 offset-lg-1">
                    <img src="http://brotherslab.thesoftking.com/html/lotten/demo/assets/images/shape/banner-one.png" class="banner-one">
                </div>


                <div class=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!---End of Home section--->







</div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put it as background image of `body`

Comment: Container div is second col and starts from middle of the page.. notice col-md-6 col-lg-6 classes classes.. image is on the right of the container div

Comment: You can put it as background of "home-land home-section" div and play with background-position (background-position: top right;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed image and added banner class to root div.
Changed also banner class to:

```
.banner-one {
background-image: url(http://brotherslab.thesoftking.com/html/lotten/demo/assets/images/shape/banner-one.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```js
// Navbar scroll js //

jQuery(function($) {
  "use strict";

  // get the value of the bottom of the #main element by adding the offset of that element plus its height, set it as a variable
  var mainbottom = $('#main').offset().top;

  // on scroll,
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {

    // we round here to reduce a little workload
    stop = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());
    if (stop > mainbottom) {
      $('.navbar').addClass('past-main');
      $('.navbar').addClass('effect-main')
    } else {
      $('.navbar').removeClass('past-main');
    }

  });


  // Collapse navbar on click

  $(document).on('click.nav', '.navbar-collapse.in', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('a')) {
      $(this).removeClass('in').addClass('collapse');
    }
  });


  /*-----------------------------------
  ----------- Scroll To Top -----------
  ------------------------------------*/

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
      $('#back-top').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('#back-top').fadeOut();
    }
  });
  // scroll body to 0px on click
  $('#back-top').on('click', function() {
    $('#back-top').tooltip('hide');
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 1500);
    return false;
  });




  /* ------ jQuery for Easing min -- */

  // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
  $('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').on('click', function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 54)
        }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  // Closes responsive menu when a scroll trigger link is clicked
  $('.js-scroll-trigger').on('click', function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
  });

  // Activate scrollspy to add active class to navbar items on scroll
  $('body').scrollspy({
    target: '#mainNav',
    offset: 54
  });










});
```

```css
/*----- Main Classes -----*/

html * {
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* --- Font Styles ---*/

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 16px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 14px;
}


/*------  Navbar Styling ------*/

.navbar {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #563D7C;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
}

.navbar span.navbar-toggler-icon::before {
  outline: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.navbar-nav {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #563D7C;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  color: #563D7C;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.nav-white .nav-item .nav-link {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav-white .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
  color: #F1F1F1;
}

.nav-white .navbar-brand {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.99) !important;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .nav-white .navbar-brand {
    color: #4957B8;
  }
  .nav-white .nav-item .nav-link {
    color: #4957B8;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 240px) {
  .navbar.past-main {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.99) !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.3);
  }
  .navbar.effect-main {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .nav-white.past-main .nav-item .nav-link {
    color: #4957B8;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .navbar.past-main .nav-item .nav-link {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .nav-white.past-main .navbar-brand {
    color: #4957B8;
  }
  .nav-white.effect-main {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  /*----------------------------------------------------------
    --------------- 3. Hero Home Styling Starts -------------------
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
  .home-section h4 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #b2bcc1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.2;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .home-section img {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  .hero-home h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 1.2;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
  }
  .home-section h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #364655;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 1.2;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
  }
  .hero-home p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #EFEFEF;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 1.6;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .home-section p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #627382;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 1.6;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  /*---------- home-section Styling --------------- */
  .home-section {
    padding: 100px 0 50px 0 !important;
    background: #4529f9;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 40rem;
    padding-top: 72px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  .home-section .home-content {
    text-align: center;
  }
  /*-----------------------------------------------------------------
    ------------------  Media Queries  -------------------
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
  @media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-nav {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    .navbar-nav .nav-item {
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-right: 15px;
      font-size: 0.85rem;
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    .home-split .home-left {
      padding: 200px 20px 150px 20px;
    }
    .home-section {
      padding: 150px 0 150px 0 !important;
    }
    .home-section.col-sm-5 {
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -webkit-flex: 0 0 50%;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
      flex: 0 0 50%;
      max-width: 50%;
    }
  }
}

.banner-one {
  background-image: url(http://brotherslab.thesoftking.com/html/lotten/demo/assets/images/shape/banner-one.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Landing Page</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap , Main CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <!-- fontawesome kit -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04ca3524f6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!---Nav bar section--->

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md nav-white navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Label</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto navbar-right">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#main">Home</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Features</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Buy Now</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!---End of Nav bar section--->


  <!---Home section--->
  <div id="main" class="main">
    <div class="home-land home-section banner-one">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-center">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <div class="home-content">
              <h4>Label for your big data needs</h4>
              <h1>Manage all your data at just one place</h1>
              <p>Best in class big data software and analytics services will render your chunks into meaningful data.</p>
              <div class="subform subform-alt wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                <form id="signup" class="formee formee-alt" action="assets/php/subscribe.php" method="post">
                  <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><input class="right inputnew" type="submit" title="Send" value="Get Access" />
                </form>
                <div id="response"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-note">
                <p>14-day free trial and no credit card required.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 offset-lg-1">
          </div>


          <div class=""></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <!---End of Home section--->







  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Farouk, I mean  i wanna put image in the  landing page right side

Comment: So what happens to "Manage all your data at just one place
Best in class big data software and analytics services will render your chunks" section? get pushed to the right or the image is in the right as background?

Comment: yes , i got it and   do the small changes, now its working

Answer (score 0):

I  put the  `banner-one` class   with 'home-land home-section' div , now it's working

```js
// Navbar scroll js //

jQuery(function($) {
    "use strict";

        // get the value of the bottom of the #main element by adding the offset of that element plus its height, set it as a variable
        var mainbottom = $('#main').offset().top;

        // on scroll,
        $(window).on('scroll',function(){

        // we round here to reduce a little workload
        stop = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());
        if (stop > mainbottom) {
            $('.navbar').addClass('past-main');
            $('.navbar').addClass('effect-main')
        } else {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('past-main');
       }

      });


  // Collapse navbar on click

   $(document).on('click.nav','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('a') ) {
    $(this).removeClass('in').addClass('collapse');
   }
  });


    /*-----------------------------------
    ----------- Scroll To Top -----------
    ------------------------------------*/

    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
          $('#back-top').fadeIn();
      } else {
          $('#back-top').fadeOut();
      }
    });
    // scroll body to 0px on click
    $('#back-top').on('click', function () {
      $('#back-top').tooltip('hide');
      $('body,html').animate({
          scrollTop: 0
      }, 1500);
      return false;
    });




  /* ------ jQuery for Easing min -- */

    // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
    $('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').on('click', function () {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 54)
          }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
          return false;
        }
      }
    });

    // Closes responsive menu when a scroll trigger link is clicked
    $('.js-scroll-trigger').on('click', function () {
      $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    });

    // Activate scrollspy to add active class to navbar items on scroll
    $('body').scrollspy({
      target: '#mainNav',
      offset: 54
    });










});
```

```css
/*----- Main Classes -----*/

html * {
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}





/* --- Font Styles ---*/

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 16px;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 14px;
}






/*------  Navbar Styling ------*/

.navbar {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease;
    transition: 0.5s all ease;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #563D7C;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler {
    border: none;
}

.navbar span.navbar-toggler-icon::before {
    outline: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.navbar-nav {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: 0.5s all ease;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #563D7C;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    color: #563D7C;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.nav-white .nav-item .nav-link {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav-white .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
    color: #F1F1F1;
}

.nav-white .navbar-brand {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    .navbar {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.99) !important;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .nav-white .navbar-brand {
        color: #4957B8;
    }
    .nav-white .nav-item .nav-link {
        color: #4957B8;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 240px) {

    .navbar.past-main {
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.99) !important;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.3);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.3);
    }

    .navbar.effect-main {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }


    .nav-white.past-main .nav-item .nav-link {
        color: #4957B8;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

    .navbar.past-main .nav-item .nav-link {
        font-weight: 500;
    }

    .nav-white.past-main .navbar-brand {
        color: #4957B8;
    }

    .nav-white.effect-main {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    /*----------------------------------------------------------
    --------------- 3. Hero Home Styling Starts -------------------
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/

    .home-section h4 {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #b2bcc1;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        line-height: 1.2;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .home-section img {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }


    .hero-home h1 {
        font-size: 32px;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        color: #FFF;
        line-height: 1.2;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
    }

    .home-section h1 {
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #364655;
        color: #FFF;
        line-height: 1.2;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
    }

    .hero-home p {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: #EFEFEF;
        color: #FFF;
        line-height: 1.6;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .home-section p {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: #627382;
        color: #FFF;
        line-height: 1.6;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    /*---------- home-section Styling --------------- */
    .home-section {
        padding: 100px 0 50px 0 !important;
        background:#4529f9 ;height: 100vh;
        min-height: 40rem;
        padding-top: 72px;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }

    .home-section .home-content {
        text-align: center;
    }











    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------
    ------------------  Media Queries  -------------------
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    @media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {

        .navbar-nav {
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        .navbar-nav .nav-item {
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-right: 15px;
            font-size: 0.85rem;
            font-weight: 400;
        }


        .home-split .home-left {
            padding: 200px 20px 150px 20px;
        }

        .home-section {
            padding: 150px 0 150px 0 !important;
        }

        .home-section.col-sm-5 {
            -webkit-box-flex: 0;
            -webkit-flex: 0 0 50%;
            -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
            flex: 0 0 50%;
            max-width: 50%;
        }
    }
}


.banner-one {



    width: 100%;

    background-image: url(http://brotherslab.thesoftking.com/html/lotten/demo/assets/images/shape/banner-one.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 880px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;


    background-size: 68%;
    background-position: top right;



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap , Main CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
   

    <!-- fontawesome kit -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04ca3524f6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!---Nav bar section--->

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md nav-white navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Label</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto navbar-right">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#main">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Features</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Buy Now</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

</div>

<!---End of Nav bar section--->


<!---Home section--->
<div id="main" class="main">
    <div class="home-land home-section banner-one">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-center">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="home-content">
                        <h4>Label for your big data needs</h4>
                        <h1>Manage all your data at just one place</h1>
                        <p>Best in class big data software and analytics services will render your chunks into meaningful data.</p>
                        <div class="subform subform-alt wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                            <form id="signup" class="formee formee-alt" action="assets/php/subscribe.php" method="post">
                                <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><input class="right inputnew" type="submit" title="Send" value="Get Access" />
                            </form>
                            <div id="response"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-note">
                            <p>14-day free trial and no credit card required.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 offset-lg-1">
                   
                </div>


                <div class=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!---End of Home section--->







</div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</body>
</html>
```